# TYPO3: logout button in menu

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid

What's the best way to add a "logout" button in the menu. I am using the extensions "fe_users" and "femanager". I found a few solutions on the web but none do work.

Comment: Best would be via ajax, to ensure, your page/content can be cached.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any link containing the GET-Parameter `?logintype=logout` will cause the system to process a logout. You can either add a link with this parameter to a HMENU / TMENU or create a page of type external link in the backend and add the parameter to a link to your page and only show this page in menues when logged in.

Comment: This might result in a "Request parameters could not be validated (&cHash empty)" error. You may [disable this validation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63602834/1149880) at your own risk.