# TYPO3 Form: Request parameters could not be validated

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I created a contanct form in TYPO3 9.5.20. Everything worked fine so far.
Yesterday I created a new site-configuration in order to have a better looking url-path und suddenly the form submission doesn't work anymore. I'm getting the following error:

> Page Not Found (404) Request parameters could not be validated (&cHash
> comparison failed) More information regarding this error might be
> available online.

Any advise what could be the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research I could fix the error by adding the following configuration to the global configuration in TYPO3:

`[FE][pageNotFoundOnCHashError]= 0`

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting a 404 error when passing additional GET params in URL.

After removing `[FE][cacheHash][enforceValidation] = true` from LocalConfiguration.php the GET params work again.

[According to TYPO3 documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/Configuration/Typo3ConfVars/FE.html#enforcevalidation) it is advised to keep `[FE][cacheHash][enforceValidation]` set to `true`.
And if you need additional params, add them to the `excludedParameters` list:

```
'FE' => [
  'cacheHash' => [
    'enforceValidation' => true,
    'excludedParameters' => [
      'test',
    ],
  ],
]
```